# Localize the string in iOS

Tags: swift, localization, nsstring

I have localisation problems,

Here is my code:

```
 func attributedText()->NSAttributedString{ <br>
 self.lbltext.text = 
 NSLocalizedString("\n" + “Best Friends“ + "\n" + "\n" + “James” + “Kelvin” +“Favorite Food” + "\n" + "\n" +"(1) Burger” + "\n" +"(2) Fried Food” + "\n" +"(3) Beer”, comment: "")
 let string = "\n" + “Best Friends“ + "\n" + "\n" + “James” + “Kelvin” + “Favorite Food” + "\n" + "\n" +
                "(1) Burger” + "\n" +
                "(2) Fried Food” + "\n" +
                "(3) Beer” as NSString<br><br>
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])

 let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17.0)]
```

**// Part of string to be bold**

```
 attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: string.rangeOfString(“Best Friends“))
 attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: string.rangeOfString(“Favorite Food”))
 return attributedString
 }<br><br>
 self.lbltext = attributedText()
```

====================

In **Main.strings** file,my code is

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "\n" + “Best Friends“ + "\n" + "\n" + “James” + “Kelvin” +“Favorite Food” + "\n" + "\n" + "(1) Burger” + "\n" + "(2) Fried Food” + "\n" + "(3) Beer”; ObjectID = "kDi-LM-j5f"; */ <br><br>
"kDi-LM-j5f.text" = "\n" + “Best Friends“ + "\n" + "\n" + “James” + “Kelvin” + “Favorite Food” + "\n" + "\n" + "(1) Burger” + "\n" + "(2) Fried Food” + "\n" +"(3) Beer”;  <br>
```

=======================

In **Localizable.strings** file,

```
"\n" + “Best Friends“ + "\n" + "\n" + “James” + “Kelvin” + “Favorite Food” + "\n" + "\n" +"(1) Burger” + "\n" +"(2) Fried Food” + "\n" +"(3) Beer” = "my translate text....";
```

Error is incorrect data format.

I think it is caused because of "\n" .

Answer (score 0):

I this you should try to simplify what you ask `NSLocalizedString` to provide to you.

If you look at your current code:

```
NSLocalizedString("\n" + “Best Friends“ + "\n" + "\n" + “James” + “Kelvin” +“Favorite Food” + "\n" + "\n" +"(1) Burger” + "\n" +"(2) Fried Food” + "\n" +"(3) Beer”, comment: "")
```

Then I'm guessing that what you'd really like to localize is the "Best Friends", "Favorite Food", "Burger" (or maybe not Burger as that's called pretty much the same all over, come to think of it :)), "Fried Food" and "Beer".

So, I would split the string into pieces, have my `Localizable.strings` contain keys for the individual parts and then let `NSLocalizedString` provide those individual parts and then worry about putting it together myself.

Something like:

```
let bestFriends = NSLocalizedString("Best Friends", comment: "")
let favoriteFood = NSLocalizedString("Favorite Food", comment: "") 
let burger = NSLocalizedString("Burger", comment: "")
let friedFood = NSLocalizedString("Fried Food", comment: "")
let beer = NSLocalizedString("Beer", comment: "")

let text = "\(bestFriends) \n \n James Kelvin \(favoriteFood) \n\n (1)\(burger) \n(2) \(friedFood) \n(3)  \(beer)"
```

And then...I'm not sure "\n" works in Strings like you expect, so maybe you should rethink that...I'm sure the compiler will let you know though :)

Hope this helps you.